# Flag status for retracted flags

Tags: feature-request, flags

When we see flags summary page, *retracted flags* can be seen as *self-removed* status. Which I was seeing the first time, so I thought SO/SE had added something new. I hovered over it and it displays the time. When I clicked on a link it was redirected to that retracted flagged question and there was *retracted flag 1* on the right side (where flag stats are shown).

**Question:**

Flag status as self-removed creates the confusion whether a post was removed itself or the flagger has retracted the flag.

Can we have a single status or name as retracted?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Flag Retracted" and "Removed by Author?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sounds good to me. Removed by Author is already the message you get when following a link to a self-removed question, so why not on flags as well.

Comment: term *self-removed* seems to be more towards post was removed by author, why can't we simply show *Retracted*. or a single status name.

Comment: we saw self-removed in flagged post lists and on flag stats we saw *Retracted*. keeping one name either Retracted or self-removed is more helpful.

Comment: Self-removed is non-obvious in this context. Who removed what? Did the OP remove the question or did you remove the flag? Flags have no author, so Removed by Author is explicit and unambiguous.

Comment: If OP removed the answer, it would count as Helpful. Also, on the top of the retracted page, there's a notice : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQPIh.png